# Oscdimg - Cant run because of Wrong pc type

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, deployment

So i've been wanting to create a custom win 10 image with some pre installed programs and so on and lucky i successfully created the swm file that i needed so i could create the iso.

BUT! When trying to run Oscdimg.exe from ADK it says the wrong computer type even even tho im running the 1809 vers of windows and the ADK is for that version as well.

I've tried researching but with no luck, anyone know a potential fix?

Comment: What is the exact and complete error message?

Comment: @Moab Translated from danish `File: C:/path/to/adk/oscdimg/oscdimg.exe is valid but not for this computer type`

Comment: Maybe it is not the correct bit version, 32 or 64? Dont know, google returns nothing.

Comment: its in the (x86) programs folder i dont think you can get 64 bit version of the apk

Comment: Was a wild guess, post back if you find a solution. Are there any logs for oscdimg?

Comment: No logs the only thing besides the pop on cmd is this `This version of C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\arm64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.`